# reading and inserting elements using fgets into arraybased lists C

Tags: c, arraylist

I am receiving input through stdin in the form of a line (there will be many many lines in the input), and what I want to do is take information from each line and store it into an arraybased list but I am having trouble with how to continue after a line is finished. Below is the code I have for reading in input from a single line:

```
 fgets (buff, line_size, stdin); //Get input

 //using strtok() to store first input into an array
while(token=strtok(NULL, ";,")){
      //while loop to store the rest of the line into an array called "lst"
}
```

How would I continue and start feeding the next line's input into the array list?

Comment: What do you mean by _an arraybased list_? An array? A list of arrays? An array of lists? An array of arrays? What do you want to store therein? The tokens of one single line? The tokens of all received lines? Should the line division be kept? Should all tokens of all lines be joined into just one list?

Answer (score 0):

This task would be a lot easier to do in c++

Here, `strtok` should be like so:

```
    char input[1024];
    char *separator = ",;";
    char *token = NULL;
//test1-begin
    strcpy(input, "1,2");
    token = strtok(input, separator);
    while (token)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, separator);
    }
//test1-end
    int row = 0;
    for (;; row++) {
        printf("enter comma separated numbers\n");
        fgets(input, 1024, stdin);
        if (strlen(input) < 2) break;
        token = strtok(input, separator);
        while (token) {
            token = strtok(NULL, separator);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite get why you did the strcpy? Could you please explain

Comment: That's just for testing without fgets. You can remove the part between test1-begin, test1-end

Comment: also, what does the for loop header mean? doesn't it require some initial conditions?

Comment: when I use this code, it crashes. For testing purposes I am passing in a file pointer as an argument instead of stdin, and the program correctly prints the input but it goes on to also print a bunch of empty lines and then crashes soon afterwards. Could you check this please